# Drag and drop people in Area from Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to create a web page so I can assign access zones to people by dragging the people into the zones and update the zone in the database.

I manage to use Drag and drop javascript and retrieve the list of people in the database.

But I would like to find the most optimal way to sort people in the right boxes when the page loads and then I would like to be able to change the zone number in the Mysql database when a person is dropped in a zone .

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfOEf.png)

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title> Drag and Drop</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="board">
            <div class="column column-zone1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <h2>Zone 1</h2>
                <div class="container">

        <table>
        <div class="column column-ip" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            <?php include('EmployesDrag.php')
            ?>
        </div>
        </table>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-zone2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <h2>Zone 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-zone3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
                <h2>Zone 3</h2>
            </div>
        </main>

        <script src="js/DragDrop.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php 

          //connexion à la base de donnée
          include_once "connexion.php";               
                //requête pour afficher les infos d'un employé
                $sql="SELECT prenom , nom FROM personnel";

                $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);



                if ($result)
                  {
                  // Return the number of rows in result set
                  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
                  }
        
                if($rowcount == 0){
                    //s'il n'existe pas d'employé dans la base de donné , alors on affiche ce message :
                    echo "Il n'y a pas encore d'employé ajouter !" ;
                    
                }else {

                    //si non , affichons la liste de tous les employés
                    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <article class="card" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" data-id="1"><?=$row['nom']?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                }
                  // Free result set
                  mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
            ?>
```

```
const dragStart = target => {
    target.classList.add('dragging');
};

const dragEnd = target => {
    target.classList.remove('dragging');
};

const dragEnter = event => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.add('drop');
};

const dragLeave = event => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.remove('drop');
};

const drag = event => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', event.currentTarget.outerHTML);
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
};

const drop = event => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.column').forEach(column => column.classList.remove('drop'));
    document.querySelector(`[data-id="${event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain')}"]`).remove();

    event.preventDefault();
    event.currentTarget.innerHTML = event.currentTarget.innerHTML + event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
};

const allowDrop = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
};

document.querySelectorAll('.column').forEach(column => {
    column.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    column.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
});

document.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
    if (e.target.className.includes('card')) {
        dragStart(e.target);
    }
});

document.addEventListener('dragend', e => {
    if (e.target.className.includes('card')) {
        dragEnd(e.target);
    }
});
```

To display people in the right column, I can do it by making 3 different php pages and executing the query $sql="SELECT firstname, lastname FROM personal where zoneAccess = 1";

then $sql="SELECT firstname, lastname FROM personal where zoneAccess = 2";

and then $sql="SELECT firstname, lastname FROM personal where zoneAccess = 3";

But I know that's not the right way to do it. Can you help me improve this?
And how can I do to write the number of the selected zone, in the zoneAccess field of the database?

Thanks,

Kevin.

Comment: There's a lot going on here, and it is rare for the UI and any events to cross directly over to your SQL, but I don't think I can dive too deep in a comment, nor answer in any direct way. That said, you could combine your query into a single one and let JS figure things out by doing `SELECT firstname, lastname, zoneAccess FROM personal where zoneAccess IN (1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make everything work, but my code is not optimized:

For each area from/to which I want to drag and drop, I execute one MYSQL Request to retrieve the names associated with each zone:

```
require_once('connexion.php');
$sqlZone1    = "SELECT id, nom, zoneAcces FROM personnel where zoneAcces = '1' ORDER 
                     BY id desc";
$zone1Result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlZone1);
//Fetch all zone1 list items
$zone1Items   = mysqli_fetch_all($zone1Result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Get Zone2 items
$sqlZone2     = "SELECT id, nom, zoneAcces FROM personnel where zoneAcces = '2' ORDER 
                     BY id desc";
$zone2Result    = mysqli_query($con, $sqlZone2);
//Fetch all Zone2 items
$zone2Items     = mysqli_fetch_all($zone2Result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

...
```

then I create the DIV for the area to DRAG/DROP

```
 <div id="droppable1" class="ui-widget-header">
  
 <?php foreach ($zone1Items as $key => $item) { ?>

   <div class="personnel1" data-itemid=<?php echo $item['id'] ?> >

     <p><strong><?php echo $item['nom'] ?></strong></p>

     <hr />

   </div>

 <?php } ?> 
  
</div>

<div id="droppable2" class="ui-widget-header">

  <?php foreach ($zone2Items as $key => $bitem) { ?>

    <div class="personnel2" data-itemid=<?php echo $bitem['id'] ?>>

      <p><strong><?php echo $bitem['nom'] ?></strong></p>

      <hr />

    </div>

  <?php } ?>

</div>
...
```

Then For each zone I create the javascript to allow drag drop and with a link to a php file for each update

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
 <script>

  $( function() {

$( ".personnel1" ).draggable();

$( "#droppable1" ).droppable({

  drop: function( event, ui ) {
     
      $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );

      var itemid = ui.draggable.attr('data-itemid')
      
      $.ajax({
         method: "POST",
       
         url: "updatePHP/update_item_status1.php",
         data:{'itemid': itemid}, 
      }).done(function( data ) {
         var result = $.parseJSON(data);
       
       });
     }
  });
});


  $( function() {

    $( ".personnel2" ).draggable();

    $( "#droppable2" ).droppable({
 
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
         
          $(this).addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
 
          var itemid = ui.draggable.attr('data-itemid')
          
          $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
           
             url: "updatePHP/update_item_status2.php",
             data:{'itemid': itemid}, 
          }).done(function( data ) {
             var result = $.parseJSON(data);
           
           });
         }
      });
  });
```

And so for each Update I've a different php file with only zoneAcces = '1' or zoneAcces = '2' or ... wich is different

```
<?php

 require_once('../connexion.php');

  $itemid  = intval($_POST['itemid']);
  
 
 //SQL query to get results from database

  $sql = "update personnel set zoneAcces = '1' where id = $itemid";

  $con->query($sql);
    
  $con->close();

  //send a JSON encded array to client
   
  echo json_encode(array('success'=>1));
```

Comment: Please don´t ask follow up questions in answers. Answers should be only the solution to your issue. If this solves your initial problem leave it as it is and ask a new question. If this doesn´t answer your question edit the question and add this as additional information.